# jQuery accodion with additional padding

Tags: jquery, resize, accordion, padding

I ve got this script which works fine:

### Javascript

```
$('.trigger').not('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').hide();
$('.trigger').click( function() {
    var trig = $(this);
    if ( trig.hasClass('trigger_active') ) {
        trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
        trig.removeClass('trigger_active');
    } else {
        $('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.trigger_active').removeClass('trigger_active');
        trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
        trig.addClass('trigger_active');
    };
    return false;
});
```

My html structure looks like this:

### HTML

```
<div class="group">
<div class="item1">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
<div class="item3">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
<div class="item4">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
<div class="item5">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
<div class="item6">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
<div class="item7">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
<div class="item8">
<div class="trigger"></div>
<div class="trigger_container"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

But when the accordion opens, i want that the div "group" gets a padding-bottom with the size of the height of the div "trigger_content". And of corse when the accordion closes, the div "group" gehts a padding-bottom of "0".

Can you help me with that?
THX

Answer (score 0):

try something like that :

```
$('.group').css('padding-bottom', $('trigger_content').height())
```

Comment: Someting is still wrong with the code, could you have a look?
http://jsfiddle.net/kfcgg/2/embedded/result/

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: You can see in the fiddle, the element "group" doesnt get the height of the element "toggle_content".

Comment: I added a callback but the parent class "group" still not changing the height:
http://jsfiddle.net/kfcgg/4/